# How force page to wait for Angular. html2pdf.it does not render AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, pdf-generation, html2pdf

I want to convert HTML pages to PDF. [html2pdf.it](http://www.html2pdf.it/) seems a good tool, as [it's open source](https://github.com/ebdrup/html2pdf.it) and I can install it in my own server.

Only is needed to add the url to the path:

> http://www.html2pdf.it/?url=

I made two simple pages. One using angularjs and other with just JavaScript. On first one Angular is not render, I see `{{text}}`. This is weird because `angularjs.org` is converted to PDF correctly. JS version works too.

**How do I force it to wait to angular to finish?**

- Codepen [Angular version](http://codepen.io/M1k3l/pen/yOpgyE?editors=1000)
- Codepen [JS version](http://codepen.io/M1k3l/pen/vGpgRg?editors=1000)
- PDF Angular version: http://www.html2pdf.it/?url=http://s.codepen.io/M1k3l/debug/yOpgyE
- PDF JS version: http://www.html2pdf.it/?url=http://s.codepen.io/M1k3l/debug/vGpgRg

Code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Minimum AngularJS page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
          <p>{{text}}</p>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular
            .module('demoApp', [])
            .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
                $scope.text = "If you see this means angularjs is working";
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT April 8 2016:

I doesn't work neither with async calls eg; `setTimeout()`

- [Codepen](http://codepen.io/M1k3l/pen/RaxMGR?editors=1000) setTimeout version
- [PDF set timeout version](http://www.html2pdf.it/?url=http://s.codepen.io/M1k3l/debug/RaxMGR):

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you try to use the ng-bind-html to render the html from a scope variable. something like the attached snippet. You will have to include the angular-sanitize.js and also include a module ngSanitize as done in the code snippet.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Minimum AngularJS page</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body ng-app="demoApp">
 <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p ng-bind-html="text"></p>
 </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-sanitize.js"></script> 
 <script>
  angular
   .module('demoApp', ['ngSanitize']) 
   .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.text = "If you see this means angularjs is working";
   });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Paras